# Run Teamcity configuration N times

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

In the set of my TeamCity configurations, I decided to make something like an aging test*. And run a single configuration for a 100 times. 
Can I make in a few simple clicks?

*aging test - test that is showing, that due time/aging, results will not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this is not possible from UI. If you run one build configuration few times without any changes, they will be merged and only 1 will be executed. If you want to run 100, you have to trigger them one by one, after the previous one finished executing.

But the better solution is to trigger builds from script using REST API  (for more details see the documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild)), if builds have different values in custom parameters they all will be put in the queue.

HOW: Define a dummy custom parameter, and trigger the build from script within a loop. Pass the value of iterating variable as parameter value. So, TeamCity will think those are different builds and execute all of them.